# How to space out rows and columns in Python Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, grid, tile

I am working on a program where it has a scroll able frame using a canvas. But inside this frame I wanted to make a tile set up. But when I tried to space out the columns and rows it does not work. Does anyone see why? I am using the grid geometry manager.

Code:

```
def fields(self):
    frame_row = 0
    frame_column = 0
    row_count = 0
    color = "red"

    for i in range(10):
        self.frame = Frame(self.bfr2, bg=color, width=229, height=120)
        self.frame.grid(row=frame_row, column=frame_column)

        self.columnconfigure(frame_column, pad=3) #Where it is supposed to add the padding between the columns.
        self.rowconfigure(frame_row, pad=3) #Where it is supposed to add the padding between the rows.

        frame_column = frame_column + 1
        row_count = row_count + 1

        if row_count == 2:
            frame_row = frame_row + 1
            frame_column = 0
            row_count = 0

            if color == "red":
                color = "green"
            else:
                color = "red"

        if color == "red":
            color = "green"
        else:
            color = "red"
```

Comment: What does "does not work" mean? Does  your program crash? Do you get an error? What error? If it doesn't crash, what it is doing that you don't want it to do?

Comment: @BryanOakley In the fields function I am trying to space out the frames I create but it is not spacing them out it is acting as if I did not use rowconfigure and columnconfigure.

Comment: "spacing out" is too vague. Are you wanting to create a checkerboard? A single long row? A single tall column? Do you want space between each colored frame? How much space?

Comment: @BryanOakley Yes I am trying to make it a checker board pattern but with like 3 pixels or 5 between each row and column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating the frames as children of `self.bfr2`, but you are calling `self.row_configure` and `self.columnconfigure` instead of `self.bfr2.rowconfigure` and `self.bfr2.columnconfigure`. What you're doing is setting the padding for the parent of the containing frame rather than the containing frame.

Comment: Thank you I was stuck on that all day just about. :D